# pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping when adding cloud_firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

when adding cloud_firestore to the dependencies of the project and press packages get or upgrade this error pop up

> Running "flutter packages get" in alaganbyasta...
>   Error on line 7, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a >block mapping.
>      cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4
>      ^
>   pub get failed (65)
>   Process finished with exit code 65

I tried to upgrade flutter itself but I modified **date_picker.dart** before so he asks me for commit before upgrading

my pubspec.yaml is

```
name: alaganbyasta
description: A new Flutter application.
dependencies:
  flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    cloud_firestore: v0.7.4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Please post the `pubspec.yaml` content. YAML is whitespace-sensitive. If you have wrong indentation you get such an error.

Comment: i edited the question and added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    cloud_firestore: v0.7.4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

to

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: v0.7.4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1568o5dqs2ukCsKQkmmf8Zfhs40h5bKRh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps you should use spaces for indentation. I have no experience with yaml and tabs. I'd expect this to work though from the screenshot, but the code you posted in your question definitely has errors (like explained in my answer).

Comment: i copied the content of the file from another flutter app and replaced it in the file of the app with the problem then add these line in the exact format
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.3     # new
then it worked fine
thanks